# É possível inserir jQuery Validate no PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

Por exemplo, no meu código php está assim:

```
if( @$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
  $sobrenome =      $_POST['sobrenome'];
  $erro = '';

  if( $nome == 'Qual é o seu sobrenome' ) {
     $erro .= '';
  } elseif ( strlen( $sobrenome ) < 2 ) {
     $erro .= 'Insira um sobrenome existente<br>';
  }
?>
```

O resultado é esse, a interface não é agradável 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que através do jquery Validate ficaria assim uma label error, uma interface mais agradável.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ao que tudo indica, sua validação está apenas sendo feita pelo PHP, não há, ou não informou o uso de nenhum plugin de validação. De qualquer forma, você pode validar pelo PHP e fazer uso de um ToolTip para criar o 'balão' sobre o campo que contém erro.

Comment: era disso que precisava @PapaCharlie

Comment: **validação** é pelo servidor, **NUNCA** omita a validação pelo PHP, pois se o usuário desabilitar o js, você não terá validação alguma.

Comment: @Papa Charlie Grandes sites por exemplo o Facebook, Gmail usa este método

Comment: Eu nunca ouvir nenhuma reclamação dos usuários

Comment: Você já trabalhou no facebook ou no gmail? Mas se você conhece bem sobre segurança, ok boa sorte.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Estou ciente que o php é o melhor método para validar campos, mas ele valida com uma interface Beta, o jquery valida com uma interface mais moderna

Comment: Certamente você não tem noção do que está falando, mas tudo bem. Não vou alongar os comentários aqui, mas se quiser usar o *bate papo* pode me chamar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18506/discussion-between-lamborghini-aventador-and-papa-charlie).

Comment: @PapaCharlie Muito obrigado entendi bem é uma maneira bem simples, era oque eu estava exatamente procurando

Comment: Bacana. Foi um modelo básico, basta incrementar conforme a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho um código que criei em JS que utiliza junto com o jQuery Validator, onde ele valida todos os campos do formulário que estejam com o atributo *required*, desta maneira você não precisa ficar validando um a um.

A única desvantagem é que não possui mensagem de erro específica para cada campo e valida apenas se o campo foi preenchido ou não, mas acredito que já possa ajudar.

Como o @PapaCharlie falou, é uma validação mais estética.

```
$('form').not('.no-validate').each(function(key, form) {
    $(form).data('validator', $(form).validate({
        ignore : "",
        errorElement : false,
        highlight : function(field) {
            $(field).closest('.form-group, .input-group').addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
        },
        unhighlight : function(field) {
            $(field).closest('.form-group, .input-group').removeClass("has-error").addClass('has-success');
        },
        errorPlacement : function() {
        }
    }));
 });
```

Para que este código funcione basta você ter o `input` dentro de uma `div` com a classe `form-group` ou `input-group`, e ter em seu CSS a classe `has-error` e `has-success` criada, veja abaixo como criei as classes.

```
.has-error .form-control, .has-error input[type="email"]{
    border-color: #A94442;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.has-success .form-control {
  border-color: #3c763d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
```

Estas duas classes estão presentes no Bootstrap, caso utilize.

Neste código você pode melhorar adicionando uma `div` com a mensagem de erro que deseja, ou esconder a `div` caso o campo esteja preenchido, etc.

É só uma ideia e uma forma simples e rápida para validar se os campos obrigatórios foram preenchidos.

Answer (score -1):

Neste caso, indico tratar essas validações antes de chegar no PHP com próprio plugin que sugeriu, pois se deixar para validar no PHP, vai ter que escrever códigos HTML em código PHP para tentar melhorar o visual, que ficaria muito desagradável, ou teria que lançar as exceções para o jQuery tratar novamente.

Comment: o meu formulário tem captcha esses plugins valida captcha também?

Comment: E se o usuário desabilitar o javascript?

Comment: Sim é possível usar captacha. @Papa Charlie tem que validar dos dois lados, sempre digo que validações do lado cliente são apenas estéticas para um resultado mais imediato e amigável, validar o lado servidor é primordial. Você também poderia não permitir o acesso caso o Javascript estivesse desabilitado e se houvesse interações muito dependentes dele, é o que acontece com outros sites como de email, mas ainda sim as validações no servidor devem existir.

Comment: @vcrzy Me indica um site bacana pra fazer download desse plugin

Comment: Olha aqui amigo, https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation  ensina até como usa-lo. Abrs